# Find integers $\alpha$ and $\beta$ such that $255\alpha + 63546\beta= gcd(255,63546).$

Tags: elementary-number-theory

I want to make sure I did the steps correctly ;

I got $\alpha = -249, \beta=1.$

$n= 63546|  255$

$x= 255  |  51$

$q= 249  |  5$

$r= 51   |  0$

$i= -249 |  1$

$j= 1    |  0 $

where $255 \times 0 + 51 \times 1 = 51.$
Then $255 \times -249 + 63546\times 1=51$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You answer is one of many. Let's first find $\gcd(255,63546)$.

Notice that $255=3 \cdot 5 \cdot 17$ and $63546 = 2 \cdot 3 \cdot 7 \cdot 17 \cdot 89$. Then the highest divisor of these two numbers is $3 \cdot 17$. Hence $\gcd(255,63546) = 51.$

Now it is relatively simple to solve the equation.

\begin{align}
255 \alpha + 63546 \beta & = 51 \\
5 \alpha + 1246 \beta & = 1 \\
5\alpha & = 1-1246 \beta \\
\alpha& = \frac{1 - 1246 \beta}{5} \\ 
\end{align}

Notice that we ended up with a linear equation. Any $\{\alpha,\beta\} \in \mathbb Z$ will work as long as the above equation is satisfied.

Your solution, $\{-249,1\}$ works.

\begin{align}
\alpha & = \frac{1-1246 \beta}{5} \\
& = \frac {1-1246 \cdot 1}{5} \\
& = -249 \\
\end{align}

In fact, there are infinitely many solutions to this equation, since it is a linear line and it goes on forever.

Comment: That makes sense. Thanks!